# Hive- Table Data to Key/ Value Pairs

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hiveql, key-value

I've been wondering how MapReduce works for Hive. More specifically, I want to understand how the data in a table is turned into key-value pairs.

I have this table with, say, 3 partitions on HDFS

```
emp_table
+---+---------------+---+----------+
| id|           name|age|department|
+---+---------------+---+----------+
|  1|   James Gordon| 30|  Homicide|
|  2| Harvey Bullock| 35|  Homicide|
|  3|Kristen Kringle| 28|   Records|
|  4|   Edward Nygma| 30| Forensics|
|  5|  Lee Thompkins| 31| Forensics|
+---+---------------+---+----------+
```

and I run this query on it

```
SELECT id, name, department, count(department) FROM emp_table GROUP BY department;
```

How would the data be broken down into key/value pairs?

My theory is that the key would be the column name and values would be the, well, values for the particular column.

```
Key         Value
id          1, 2, 3, 4, 5
name        James Gordon, Harvey Bullock, Kristen Kringle, Edward Nygma, Lee Thompkins
department  Homicide, Homicide, Records, Forensics, Forensics
```

I haven't found any resources on the net regarding this, so I'm not sure if I'm correct. Could someone help clarify this for me?

Also, please let me know if I have made any incorrect assumptions (which I suspect are many)

Comment: I have added details around your query. Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hive execution engine do generate a detailed plan to run the mapreduce. The plan consist of all the details like

- number of mapreduce job
- key-value and join condition on each of the map-reduce.

just execute the below command on hive prompt and walk through the plan to understand the key-value in mapreduce.

```
explain SELECT id, name, department, count(department) FROM emp_table GROUP BY department;
```

Must also see `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` and [a sample analysis of explain output](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Explain).